# Reading files inside a subdir within a zip file

Tags: java, zip

I have file in the following structure:

```
--BA.zip
      |
      |--- BA (directory)
            |
            |---BA_KKSSI_20201013.zip
            |      |
            |      |---BA_KKSSI_20201013.txt
            |---BA_KKSSI_20201014.zip
            |      |
            |      |---BA_KKSSI_20201014.txt
            |---BA_KKSSI_20201015.zip
                   |
                   |---BA_KKSSI_20201015.txt
```

I need to read BA_KKSSI_20201013.txt without extracting the parent file which is BA.zip
I have already written parts of code to read if there is no sub dirs. For example:

```
public static String readChildZip(Path zipPath) throws IOException {

    try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath.toFile())) {

        // since there is only one text file
        ZipEntry textFile = zipFile.entries().nextElement();

        // the zip
        System.out.println(zipFile.getName());

        InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(textFile);

        String contents = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return contents;
    }
}
```

Above code can process the last zip and txt part (i.e., if there are no sub-dirs within a zip)

I looked through most of the SO posts and all of them propose extracting the sub-directory first and then read through the secondary zip files.

Is there a way to do this without extracting in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the contents of the first text file inside the first Zip file in `zipPath`.

```
public static String readChildZip(Path zipPath) throws IOException {
    try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath.toFile())) {
        ZipEntry childZipEntry = zipFile.entries().nextElement();
        try (InputStream childInputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(childZipEntry);
            ZipInputStream childZipStream = new ZipInputStream(childInputStream)) {
            childZipStream.getNextEntry();
            return new String(childZipStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    }
}
```

And this will print the contents of all text files inside the first Zip file in `zipPath`.

```
public static void readChildZipAll(Path zipPath) throws IOException {
    try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath.toFile())) {
        ZipEntry childZipEntry = zipFile.entries().nextElement();
        try (InputStream childInputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(childZipEntry);
            ZipInputStream childZipStream = new ZipInputStream(childInputStream)) {
            ZipEntry grandChildEntry;
            while ((grandChildEntry = childZipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.println(grandChildEntry + ":"
                    +  new String(childZipStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ZipInputStream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to read entries in the "outer" zip file as zip files as well.

Meaning open the zip file as you have but then iterate over and if a entry is a zipfile itself you create a ZipInputStream with the InputStream for that ZipEntry.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using NIO ZIP File System or `ZipInputStream` if wanting to scan a ZIP.

Here is an example of using ZIP File System in a recursive scanner which can be used to inspect any level of depth of JAR/ZIP/WAR/EAR hierarchy. You should adapt to suit own purposes for whatever action you need to perform on the content, this example just cats any ".txt" files to the console.

Note that ZIP File System returns zip filesystem `Path` objects which can be used with NIO `Files.xxx()` calls such as `Files.find()` and `Find.copy()` just like you would use for `Path` that originate from default HDD filesystems.

```
private static Pattern ZIP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\.(jar|war|ear|zip)");
public static void traverseZip(Path zip) {
    System.out.println("traverseZip "+zip.toAbsolutePath());

    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip)) {
        for (Path root : fs.getRootDirectories()) {
            try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(root, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p,a) -> true)) {
                stream.forEach(entry -> {
                    System.out.println(zip.toString()+" -> "+entry);

                    // SOME ACTION HERE, for example
                    if (entry.toString().endsWith(".txt")) {
                        cat(entry, System.out);
                    }

                    if (ZIP_PATTERN.matcher(entry.toString()).matches() && Files.isRegularFile(entry)) {
                        traverseZip(entry);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}

private static void cat(Path path, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        Files.copy(path, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

Launch with:

```
traverseZip(Path.of("some.zip"));
```